# Similarity of Infinite Direct Sums Vs. Infinite Direct Products Across Categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Let $|R|=|S|=\infty$. In many concrete categories, I know $R^S$ can be identified as the set of all functions from S to R, and the much "smaller" $R^{\oplus S}$ can be identified as the subset of $R^S$ containing only elements with finitely many non-null coordinates. **I am looking for a deep reason why this is so across these categories.**

In topology, the distinction is obvious, and the product topology is defined as the coarser of the two. However, this is not a deep or fundamental reason as to why $R^{\oplus S}$ has the above characterization in algebra, category theory, or set theory. For example, using just the universal properties of the product and coproduct, it is not at all obvious to me why $R^{\oplus S}$ is characterized the way it is above.

If it is simply defined this way, then why? If it can be derived, then may I see such a derivation?

Comment: Simply put, if you the direct sum (in categories in which we know what "direct sum" means) satisfies the (more general) universal property of the coproduct. Since the coproduct is a universal construction, the direct sum _is_ (up to unique isomorphism) the coproduct.

Comment: Well, yes, but I am really looking for a deep explanation as to why the particular construction (especially for infinite-cardinality objects) satisfies the coproduct among so many categories.

Comment: @AlexG.:  You know, you could have put that in the Answer box...

Comment: This answer may seem flippant, but it is not:  Because $(1,1,1,\dots)$ is too far away from $(0,0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: Definitely, in topology. Anyway, it is not too far away for the direct product. An explanation, for example, as to why it is "too far away" with regard to the coproduct universal property but not with regard to the product universal property in abstract algebra would be nice to know.

Comment: You say you want an explanation for the fact that in "so many categories" an infinite coproduct is the subset of the product where finitely many coordinates are "non-null"; but I disagree with your impression that this happens very often. Basically it happens in categories that are similar to Abelian groups, but it fails for example in these categories I'm fond of: sets, topological spaces, graphs, categories, groups, commutative rings, rings, partial orders, etc. I don't think you'll find a "deep explanation" that is substantially different from a proof that it holds in Abelian groups.

Comment: That would be useful. I have simply encountered many cases where considering sets of infinite sequences that are "eventually zero" is substantially and deeply different from sets of infinite sequences. My intuition tells me this two objects can be formalized well, as in R-Mod, but more generally. The difference between the box topology and the product topology is a great example in topology. It is considerable in just the general topic of convergence across many areas. Of course, R-Mod, Ab, and Vect are other examples. If this isn't often, it is profound.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the *operations* in the structures are defined to be *finitary*.

E.g., for Abelian groups, as you said, $R^{\oplus S}$ should satisfy the universal property of coproduct, so this should consist of the $|S|$ copies of $R$, and everything else that is needed to generate the given structure, which are the *formal sums* of these elements in this case.

But the very definition of Abelian group (module, ring, etc.) only requires a *finitary addition* operation, so these formal sums, required by the structure, suffice to stay finite.

Note that, in $\mathcal Top$ the $S$-fold coproduct of $R$ is rather the disjoint union of $|S|$ pieces of $R$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. That is subtle considering I cannot remember coming across a definition for a group, abelian group, and others, where "finitary" qualified "operation" (Wikipedia and Mathworld for "group" and "abelian group" for instance"). Can't an element in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be expressed as an infinite sum of elements in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$?